# When is the chi-squared test becoming virtually identical to a Fisher exact test?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, chi-squared-test, fishers-exact-test

I am conducting several hypothesis tests for caterorical variables, with several groups being compared.

I routinely use the Fisher exact test in Stata, but occasionally it may get time consuming and computationally intensive, forcing me to switch to a standard chi-squared test.

I do that assuming that the chi-squared test becomes virtually identical to a Fisher exact test when the sample is quite large and cell counts are not too small.

Is this correct? If so, in which circumstances? I am particularly interested in the following scenarios (row cells x column cells, or vice versa):

- 3 x 3
- 3 x 4
- 3 x 5
- 4 x 4
- 4 x 5
- 5 x 5

Comment: Are you looking at a test of independence in 3x2 and 4x2 tables, or at something larger than 2 on the other dimension?

Comment: @Glen_b I have edited the post